# Centos Bash Script with Postrgres database

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, centos

Hope someone can help me with this bash script which I am trying to run on a CentOS machine. I wrote a script on FreeBSD like this

```
#!/bin/sh
setenv code1 "grant select on "
setenv code2 " to testusr"

echo setting read only access
foreach table (table1 table2 table3)
  psql -c "psql -d databasename -c '$code1$table$code2'"
end
echo finished
```

Then I changed to following but it did not work. It complains for the third last line (`sudo su postgres`) Can someone help with this please?

```
#!/bin/bash
set env code1 "grant select on "
set env code2 " to testusr"

echo setting read only access
for table in 'table1 table2 table3'
  sudo su postgres -c "psql -d databasename -c '$code1$table$code2'"
do;
echo finished
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The first script looks like `csh` in spite of the `/bin/sh` shebang line.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from a few syntax errors, you should also use `sudo` to run `psql`. Among other things, it reduces the amount of nested quoting, as you no longer have to fit the entire `psql` command in a single string as the argument to `su`'s `-c` option.

```
#!/bin/bash
code1="grant select on "
code2=" to testusr"

echo setting read only access
for table in table1 table2 table3; do
  sudo -u postgres psql -d databasename -c "$code1 $table $code2"
done
echo finished
```

Comment: I still getting error ./test.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `source' table1 table2 table3

Comment: Are you running the code above? I didn't use the word "source" at all, so I don't see how you could get that error from my code.

Comment: It works great. That was my error, you were right. Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is wrong, try:

```
#!/bin/bash
code1="grant select on"
code2="to testusr"

echo "setting read only access"
for table in 'table1 table2 table3'
  su postgres -c "psql -d databasename -c $table"
do;
echo "finished"
```

Comment: Thanks. It is again giving me syntax error: syntax error near unexpected token `su'
./test.sh: line 16: `  su postgres -c "psql -d databasename '$code1$table$code2'"'

Comment: You also need to drop the quotes from the list in the for loop.

Comment: You are right. I dropped the quotes from the loop but same time added $code1 and $code2 but the tables are postgres tables, so it is not working. Seems i may need to re-write the script with a different logic